# Novice: Updating old IE html to modern standards

Tags: html

I would like to find **resources** for figuring out how to update code that only works correctly on Internet Explorer. It is frustrating to have to switch back and forth.

The IE code has user forms that will not display correctly, if at all. Data entered cannot be "submitted". Popups will not work even though the site is trusted and popups allowed.

I guess it could be rephrased what makes a site IE specific?

**edit**
The question was to find where the resources were to answer my own question. I am a old Self-Taught Noob, and would rather find a **resource** to learn from. Teach a man to fish...
The msdn site pointed to by @Sunny Alhat, was perfect for my needs.

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. Please see [ask].

Comment: The short answer is that no _site_ is IE-specific. Bits of code may be, however. It's a matter of analyzing each script for obsolete proprietary techniques.

Comment: Unless it's a massive amount of code, you're probably better off re-writing than updating, the web has rather moved forwards since IE only sites were "normal" and there are probably a lot of ways it could be improved other than just making it run.

Comment: Impossible to guess since there can be millions of reasons why. You need to show code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the MSDN Document for compatibility : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dn384059(v=vs.85)